# How to reduce the saturation of of laptop monitor in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, compiz, color-management

I want to reduce the saturation of my laptop display as its very high and hurts my eyes. I own a Dell XPS 15z. Also, I would be very grateful if anybody can help me to show how all the color management of laptop display can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a **color** option in **System Settings**.

Comment: Are you looking for something like GNOME Color Manager? https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gnome-color-manager/

Answer (score 5):

Install  ccsm (compiz config settings manager) and compiz plugins:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

In CCSM,  enable the `Opacity, Brightness, Saturation` Plugin. In that plugin, you can reduce the saturation (I myself make saturation zero and use invert plugin to invert colors (white on black is less strenuous on eyes when casual reading/browsing) generally to reduce eye-strain :))

To use the OBS plugin, simply make a New rule which can be used to match windows by name, type, class, etc. For example, to match all windows, use `type=any`

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.10, thanks a lot. Note that on a laptop, you should be able to use the Shift + brightness keys as shortcuts.