# How to increase display colors saturation?

Tags: compiz, display, color-management

I tried to follow the guide on this page:
[How to reduce the saturation of of laptop monitor in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455900/how-to-reduce-the-saturation-of-of-laptop-monitor-in-ubuntu-14-04)

but CompizConfig saturation settings do no effect. I'm on Ubuntu Studio.

[image]

My laptop screen doesn't have fancy colors, so increasing saturation would help a lot.

Comment: OK, I've made Compiz work with this comment:
compiz --replace

but with this utility it is only possible to decrease the saturation as 100% is the original value. Can't go over this.

So the question is how to increase display saturation to improve colors?